# Retrieve property from class through baseclass C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called ModelBase:

```
public abstract class ModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
    public ModelBase 
    {
        ProcessObjects.Instance.AddProcessObject(name, this);
    }
    public abstract void Dispose();
    public String Name { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
}

public class SomeModel1: ModelBase
{
    public String customprop1 { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel2: ModelBase
{
    public String customprop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I keep a list of all object instances in an application singleton. Now somewhere else in the application I want to retrieve customprop2 from SomeModel2 using this singleton list. I can retrieve the object as modelbase object and cast it:

```
SomeMethod()
{
    if(_obj.Name == "SomeModel2"){
        var _obj = obj as SomeModel2;
        var _customProp2 = obj.customprop2 ;
    }
}
```

But ideally i want to just try to retrieve the value straight from the object instance by knowing it is there in the parent of the basemodel.

```
try{
   //Some code to automatically cast the object as parent.
   var _customProp2 = _obj.customProp2;
}catch{
   //Notify user that his request failed
}
```

The reason for this is that the user can write into a textbox and start a logging function for that particular property.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a virtual property/method in the base class and override it in your derived class. This way you can retrieve the values from the object with base class reference, whenever you want.

Comment: In my Base Class I have:         public abstract float getOutput();.. Each Parent must implement this method. But this is not really what i want to do for each property. Was hoping for a way to make it less type strong.